# Is there an up-to-date professional analysis of different "mining shield" technologies?

Tags: difficulty, hashpower, mining-technical-details

E.g. [Digishield](http://www.reddit.com/r/Digibyte/comments/1zjeso/eli5_what_is_digishield/), [Gravity Well](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21730/how-does-the-kimoto-gravity-well-regulate-difficulty) etc.

As a non-miner, I only hear bits and pieces about these algorithms. Is there a comprehensive resource with details on the history of these algorithsm and relative performance and weaknesses?